# SignalR Siverlight Cliet side code

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, client, signalr

I am trying to write a simplest silverlight client code for method which can be called from server without parameters. Bellow is my code in VB:

```
hubProxy.On(Of String)("received", Function() Context.Post(Sub() textBox.Text += "Notified!", Nothing))
```

But I am getting error “Expression does not produce a value”.
Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET `Function`s *must* return a value. Since your anonymous function only has one expression, `Context.Post(Sub() textBox.Text += "Notified!", Nothing)`, the value produced by that expression is returned by the `Function`. The problem is that your one expression doesn't produce a value at all.

Since [`Context.Post`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/vstudio/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) is itself a `Sub` (or void-returning in C/C# parlance) instead of a `Function`, there is no value to return from the `Function` you pass to `hubProxy.On`.

Long story short: the `Function` you are passing into `hubProxy.On` should really be a `Sub` since it doesn't return a value. You are already using an anonymous `Sub` in your call to `Context.Post`:

```
hubProxy.On(Of String)("received",
    Sub() Context.Post(Sub() textBox.Text += "Notified!", Nothing)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot halter73 for your guidance. Yes I missed this vital point about functions. You set the ball rolling again. Your post was very critical help for me.I used :
hubProxy.[On](Of String)("received", Sub(data As String) Context.Post(Sub() textBox.Text += data, Nothing))
In fact I admit I found little help online about  Context.Post or Context.Send in VB.net after much  searching.  Can someone please point to some online resources or books about the use of these commands?